# Changing reason for close votes

Tags: support, feature-request, close-reasons, closing

I accidentally retracted my close vote on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585629/practice-math-learn) question.
How can I (have this) reset?
Also, I think there should be a **grace period** (say 5 minutes, like with comment editing) for that, since the error occured because I wanted to change my voting *reason* and not retract the vote itself.